# .NET: why Groups in ListView does not work? Are there any limitations?

Tags: .net, winforms, listview, grouping

Here is the code:

```
    private void displayOrders(ListView pView)
    {
        pView.BeginUpdate();
        try
        {
            pView.Items.Clear();
            pView.Groups.Clear();

            List<string> uniqueValues = new List<string>();
            foreach (XxxOrder order in AppDocument.Instance.OrdersList)
            {
                ListViewItem li = new ListViewItem(new string[] { order.RecvTime, order.OrderNo, order.ErrorCode.ToString() });
                string value = order.OrderNo;
                int idx = uniqueValues.IndexOf(value);
                if (idx < 0) uniqueValues.Add(value);
                pView.Items.Add(li);
            }
            if (uniqueValues.Count < (int)(pView.Items.Count * 0.90f))
            {
                pView.ShowGroups = true;
                pView.Groups.Clear();
                ListViewGroup[] groupsArray = new ListViewGroup[uniqueValues.Count];
                int i=0;
                foreach (string it in uniqueValues)
                {
                    groupsArray[i++] = new ListViewGroup(it, it);
                }
                pView.Groups.AddRange(groupsArray);
            }
        }
        finally { pView.EndUpdate(); }
    }
```

After this code executed I can see all items belong to one group called "Default".

Why is that? 
Are there any limitations by number of items and groups? In this case I have list items 7841 and I got 6629 unique Order# values, so 6629 groups.

Or maybe there is limitation by column order? So, group key expected to be only a 1st column?...

Or should groups be added first and only list items added?

Could you please advise?

*Note: it is .NET 3.5. Application use System.Windows.Forms. OS=Windows 10 Pro x64.*

Thank you in advance.

PS. I just tried to collect unique values first, then add groups, then add list items - that did not help. :-\
So, I'm quite puzzled - if that feature of ListView control in .NET Windows.Forms is working at all?!

Comment: Not adding any items to a group is the standard mistake.  That code snippet doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

You need to properly assign [ListViewItem.Group Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.group(v=vs.90).aspx).

In your case, something like this:

```
// ...
pView.Groups.AddRange(groupsArray);
foreach (ListViewItem item in pView.Items)
    item.Group = pView.Groups[item.SubItems[1].Text];
// ...
```

Comment: Ah... There is a Group property also in a list item. I missed it. I remember when I was developed own list view with grouping, I made it in-one-place-defined, so not expected Microsoft made it that way. Anyway, thank you.